# pandas can't drop_duplicates with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Series` that looks like this:

```
>>> s.head(6)
7A017  Quadratic            0.000382
       Quad + derivative    0.000055
7A018  Quadratic            0.000399
       Quad + derivative    0.000070
7A020  Quadratic            0.000363
       Quad + derivative    0.000076
dtype: float64
>>> len(s)
770
```

I want to unstack it so that the inner index levels become columns. But I get an error:

```
>>> s.unstack()
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Indeed, I have some duplicates:

```
>>> s.index.value_counts().value_counts()
1    674
2     48
dtype: int64
>>> pd.Series(s.index.duplicated()).value_counts()
False    722
True      48
dtype: int64
```

The problem is, I can't get rid of them.

```
>>> s[s.index.drop_duplicates()].index.value_counts().value_counts()
1    674
2     48
dtype: int64
```

Here's a closer look at the index.

```
>>> s.head(6).index
MultiIndex([('7A017',         'Quadratic'),
            ('7A017', 'Quad + derivative'),
            ('7A018',         'Quadratic'),
            ('7A018', 'Quad + derivative'),
            ('7A020',         'Quadratic'),
            ('7A020', 'Quad + derivative')],
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the problem. `drop_duplicates` was working fine. Using the result as an index was the wrong approach, though.

```
>>> s.iloc[~s.index.duplicated()].index.value_counts().value_counts()
1    722
dtype: int64
```